# Name for numbers where only one bit is set

Tags: numbers, bit-manipulation

Is there a name for or common way to describe numbers where in binary only one bit would be set?

```
00000001 1
00000010 2
00000100 4
00001000 8
...
```

Comment: "numbers whose binary representation has a single bit set". Rolls of your tongue, no?

Comment: How universally useful would such a term be?

Comment: No it's okay, "powers of two" will suffice. I just wondered because I'm no mathematician, but I know there are "real" numbers, "prime" numbers and so on. I wondered if in computer science terms there was a way to refer to them somehow. In this case it was for an iterator method that would return them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powers of Two: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powers_of_two

Answer (score 4):

You could call them powers of two.

Answer (score 1):

Flags or bit fields http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field